# Solve non-linear ode system as a function of $t$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I need to solve this ode' system
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot x=y\\\dot y=-x+x^2=x(x-1)
\end{cases}
$$
To solve it as a function $x(y)$ or $y(x)$ is trivial, but I need the solution as a function of time: $\left(x(t),y(t)\right)$.

The system has a first integral: $H(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2+y^2\right)-\frac{1}{3}x^3$. In particular, if no general solution is possible, I'm searching for a solution for $H=\frac{1}{6}$.

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: The first equation implies $\ddot x=\dot y$. Substitute that into the second equation to obtain an equivalent 2nd order ODE

Comment: @DavidH How does that improve the situation?

Comment: If you are are looking for solutions with $H=1/6$, then note that the system is equivalent to $\dot{x}(t) = \sqrt{2(H-V(x(t)))} = \sqrt{1/3 - 2V(x(t))}$, where $V(x) =-x^3/3 +x^2/2$. Then you have to compute (or rather study) the antiderivative $\int 1/\sqrt{1/3-2V(x)} dx$.

Comment: @user10676 Actually Wolfram solves the integral. But it is a hell. I don't there is a way of isolating $x$ afterwards.
Maybe there is something wrong in the problem of the book.

Comment: What does the book ask you to do ? You can't expect to find a nice formula for the solutions. All you can do is study them. Note that the value $H=1/6$ is very particular ($V$ has $1/6$ as maximum at $1$).

Comment: @user10676 The books asks me to compute the Melnikov distance for the homoclinic orbit of the system (that is found and $k=\frac{1}{6}$. The formula for computing the Melnikov distance requires $x(t),y(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying the 2nd order equation $\ddot x=x(x-1)$ by $\dot x$ on both sides and integrating with respect to time, we get a nonlinear 1st order equation for $x$:

$$\ddot x=x(x-1)\\
\ddot x \dot x = x(x-1)\dot x\\
\int_0^{t} \dot x(\tau)\ddot x(\tau)d\tau = \int_0^{t}x(\tau)(x(\tau)-1)\dot x(\tau)d\tau\\
\int_{\dot x_0}^{\dot x(t)} \dot x\,d\dot x = \int_{x_0}^{x(t)}x(x-1)\, dx$$

$$\frac12(\dot x^2 - \dot x_0^2)=\frac13(x-1)^3+\frac12(x-1)^2-\frac13(x_0-1)^3-\frac12(x_0-1)^2\\
\dot x^2=\dot x_0^2+\frac23(x-1)^3+(x-1)^2-\frac23(x_0-1)^3-(x_0-1)^2=f(x;x_0,\dot x_0)$$

Once we have $\dot x^2=f(x;x_0,\dot x_0)$, we can at least find an implicit equation for $x$:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt{f(x;x_0,\dot x_0)}\\
\int_{x_0}^x \frac{d\chi}{\sqrt{f(\chi;x_0,\dot x_0)}}=\int_0^t d\tau=t.$$

The final integral will in general ony be computable in terms of elliptic integrals.